# Showing an organised top down view of a 3D function in Maxima

Tags: plot, 3d, gnuplot, maxima

I asked on the math site and was told to ask this here.

I'm trying to use Maxima to show the top down view of a 3D function, the different values (height/depth) of the function will be shown using a range of colours and a colour bar that Maxima provides automatically.

Using [this website](http://www.scotchildress.com/wxmaxima/3DPlotting/3dplotting.html) I was able to put together some code for the top down view of the function (the code before I decided to leave out, as it was just load(draw)$ and the function itself):

```
wxdraw3d(
enhanced3d=true, explicit(f(y,x,15,400,1),y,0,100,x,20,30),
xu_grid=100, yv_grid=100,
xyplane=0,
view=[0,0],
zrange=[0,50],
zlabel="Gap distance (m)",
xlabel="Gap number",
ylabel="Initial velocity (ms^{-1})",
title="f(n,u,15,400,1)"
);
```

Which gives the following plot:

[image: Which gives the following plot]

As you can see, there's several issues with the plot:

- The colour bar has no label, which would use the current z-label
- The vertical axis (label, numbers and the subdivisions) should be on the left hand side
- The subdivisions of the horizontal axis should be on the bottom
- All subdivisions on the plot should appear above and not underneath
- Border should be resized so nothing is cut off or overlapping (referring to the black border around the output, the image was a crop of inside the border)

I tried another method from [this website](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/maxima-gnuplot.html) using the gnuplot code at the very bottom to give this modified code:

```
plot3d(
f(x,y,15,400,1),[x,0,100],[y,20,30],
[elevation,0],
[grid,100,100],
[zlabel,"Gap length (m)"],
[xlabel,"Gap number"],
[ylabel,"Initial velocity (ms^{-1})"],
[gnuplot_preamble,"set view map; unset surface"],
[gnuplot_pm3d,true]
);
```

However, that didn't work as it gave [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRmmz.png). Which as you can see has way more problems than the first plot. Not only is it not as clear as the first plot, it barely resembles the plot from the website, there's less info, no colour bar, no numbered axes, an annoying grid, and even the colour gradient is worse.

For the first code I used, I could not find anything about labelling the colour bar, only the range, the colour itself and whether it is on or off; and I couldn't find anything on the border size or positioning of axis labels, etc. So there's no point trying to use this code yet, especially if I get the first code to work properly. With the size of the plot, I tried wxplot_size[], but that gave the error "draw: unknown option [600,400] ", it seems to round up to the nearest hundred.

Is there any way to modify the first code such that the colour bar is labelled, the vertical axis labelling is on the other side, the small subdivisions of each axis appear over the plot, and nothing outside of the plot is cut off or overlapping? If it's not possible to move the subdivisions to be above the plot, is there anyway to remove them? I don't know much about Maxima or gnuplot .

Everything else seems fine apart from those issues, and I'm not entirely sure where else to ask about Maxima.

Comment: I don't really have a answer for you. I tried some experiments with `contour_plot` and the closest I got so far is `contour_plot (<some fcn of u and v>, [u, -4, 4], [v, -4, 4],  [legend, false], [xlabel, "My X label"], [ylabel, "My Y label"], [gnuplot_preamble, "set pm3d"]);` which doesn't have the color bar and maybe other stuff you want. You can try the Maxima mailing list to get additional ideas. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss

Comment: Actually, what is your 3D function? Can you maybe please explain `f(x,y,15,400,1),[x,0,100],[y,20,30]`? Which gnuplot version do you use?

Comment: As for gnuplot, I actually just updated it yesterday because I wasn't sure what version I was on so I updated to 5.4.1 which is the version I was using with those screenshots

Comment: The function, in terms of variables, is ut+(t²(v²-u²)(n-½))/(2l). The X is the n variable, and there will be different graphs, each with a different variable used as y, so the example I used has u as y.

Comment: @RobertDodier, I tried that along with adding a z range and colour bar range (wouldn't work otherwise), and got this error message: "Message from maxima's stderr stream: 
Warning: slow font initializationqt_processTermEvent received a GE_fontprops event. This should not have happened
["C:/Users/harry/maxout6224.gnuplot". Along with that, there's a few issues: a contour line where the function is equal to 20 (for some reason), and the vertical axis and numbers aren't on the left hand side (not only do I prefer it on that side, it's also being overlapped by the colour bar).

Comment: Harry, here's another idea. Try including `[plot_format, gnuplot], [gnuplot_out_file, "somefile.gp"]` in the options for `contour_plot`. (Probably for `draw` it's something similar.) Then look at `somefile.gp` and see if you can modify it to get the plot you want by going back to the Gnuplot documentation and trying some options.

Comment: Also at this point it might help to paste your latest Maxima commands into the problem statement.

Comment: It would be easier to just copy the function to plot.

Comment: Might sound a bit awkward, but I don't know what I'm doing with the actual gnuplot command line. The only experience I've had was with putting some code into Maxima that I found. I'm looking at the documentation (I think) and I don't know what I'm looking for our what to do. I tried a set size command I found and set it to 0.5, 0.5 and somehow the title is at the top and partially cut off by the top of the window while both the x and y axis have been messed up. Also zooming out doesn't work.

Comment: I mean writing an answer would be easier if you would have posted all of the commands necessary to plot your function, and not more. Leaving things out is ok, but the maxima function to plot is missing. In maxima formatting, no "x is n" and "y is u" comments. Just in a form that we can copy and paste into maxima and that will produce the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's modify the `wxdraw3d` command.

Maxima writes a gnuplot input file which is loaded by gnuplot afterwards, so you can check the influence of maxima commands. On my system (Debian linux) the file is in my home directory and has a name like "~/maxout_28503.gnuplot".

Most of the issues can be solved with using the gnuplot command `set view map` instead of `set view 0,0`, corresponding to maxima command `view=map` instead of `view=[0,0]`.

I have not found a "nice" way for setting the label of the colorbox. I think there is a maxima way, because by default the generated gnuplot file contains the line `set cblabel ''` which generates an empty label. But we can use the mechanism for applying any gnuplot setting: `user_preamble= ...`.

So now we have the following:

```
wxdraw3d(
    user_preamble="set cblabel 'Gap distance (m)' offset screen 0.01, 0;",
    view=map,
    enhanced3d=true,
    title="f(n,u,15,400,1)",
    xlabel="Gap number",
    ylabel="Initial velocity (ms^{-1})",
    zlabel="",
    explicit(x^2+y^2,x,-2,2,y,-2,2)
);
```

The commands written in `user_preamble=` seem to be executed just before the actual gnuplot `splot` command. They therefore can overwrite previous settings.

The command `set cblabel` sets the label of the colorbox. I have added a small offset to avoid that the label is too close.

I'm too lazy to understand your function :) so I plot another one.

This is the result:

[image: result]

---

Update to improve the picture from your comment

[image: result]

Gnuplot sometimes has problems with estimating text sizes. This can lead to ugly diagrams. You can improve the output by manually adjusting offsets and sizes.

The command `set size` changes the area of the plot within the complete image. This can be used to make some space for the colorbox label on the right side. The `set ylabel` command accepts an `offset`. We put both commands into the `user_preamble` section `wxdraw3d`:

```
wxdraw3d(
    user_preamble=[
        "set cblabel 'Gap distance (m)' offset screen 0.01, 0",
        "set ylabel offset screen -0.01,0",
        "set size 0.9,1"
    ],
    view=map,
    enhanced3d=true,
    ...
);
```

Play with all of the offset and size numbers until they fit.

Comment: Here's what I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2mZw.png; works really great but is there anyway to make it wider so the y axis label and colour bar label aren't over lapping or cut off?

Comment: @Harry I don't know for sure, but, assuming you're working with wxMaxima, is there an option in the menus to say you want plot images inline or in a separate window? Maybe try toggling that option, if there is one.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working with wxMaxima. Couldn't find anything about inline and I can seem to get it in a new window by removing the wx part of wxdraw3d(). I tried using the offset on the y axis label but I think it just goes off the screen.

Comment: @Harry Check the update on the answer please. Try small offset numbers.

Comment: @Harry Very small offset numbers, and small increments.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it now. Just a matter of finding good values which shouldn't be a problem.